# Python - Black Jack Program

Tags: python

I am creating a black jack game in python. How do I move the ending money variable to the top of the function as the function loops?

```
print "Welcome to BlackJack"

def run():

    import random
    from random import choice
    import sys
    money = 500
```

The variable 'money' changes depending if the play wins or loses. I want the ending variable to become the beginning variable when the play selected play again.

```
    raw_input("Press <ENTER> To Begin")
    print "You have $",money,"in your bank."
    bet = raw_input("How much would you like to bet?")

    b = int(bet)

    cards = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10]*4

    c1 = choice(cards)
    cards.remove(c1) 

    c2 = choice(cards)
    cards.remove(c2)

    psum = c1 + c2

    print "You were dealt a",c1,"and a",c2,"for a sum of",psum,
    print "\n"
    hs = " "

    while psum < 21 and "s" not in hs:
        hs = raw_input("Hit or Stand (h or s): ").lower()
        if "h" in hs:
            c3 = choice(cards)
            cards.remove(c3)
            psum = psum + c3
            print "You were dealt a",c3,"for a sum of",psum,
            print "\n"
        elif "s" in hs:
            print "Your final sum is",psum,

    print "\n"

    if psum > 21:
        print "Bust!" "\n" "You lose." "\n"
        money = money - b
        print "You now have $",money,"in your bank."
    elif psum == 21:
        print "You got a BlackJack!" "\n" "You win!" "\n"
        money = money + b
        print "You now have $",money,"in your bank."   
    else:
        print "Dealer's turn"

    if psum < 21:   
        c4 = choice(cards)
        cards.remove(c4) 

        c5 = choice(cards)
        cards.remove(c5)

        dsum = c4 + c5

        while dsum < 17:
            c6 = choice(cards)
            cards.remove(c6)
            dsum = dsum + c6

        if dsum > 21:
            print "Dealer's final sum is",dsum,"\n"
            print "Dealer bust! You win!" "\n"
            money = money + b
            print "You now have $",money,"in your bank."
        elif dsum < psum:
            print "Dealer's final sum is",dsum,"\n"
            print "You win!" "\n"
            money = money + b
            print "You now have $",money,"in your bank."
        elif dsum == psum:
            print "Dealer's final sum is",dsum,"\n" 
            print "Draw." "\n"
            print "You have $",money,"in your bank."
        else:
            print "Dealer's sum is",dsum,"\n"
            print "You lose." "\n"
            money = money - b
            print "You now have $",money,"in your bank."


    yn = raw_input("Would you like to play again? (y or n): ")

    if "y" in yn:
        print "\n" * 5
        run()
    else:
        print "\n" "Your total winnings is $",money,
        sys.exit()          

run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than calling `run()` each time the player chooses to play again, you should put all that code in a loop which breaks when the player chooses "no." This way the `money` variable will continue to hold its value.

**Edit:** It could definitely be advantageous (as far as clean and maintainable code) to move that code into a separate method, e.g. `deal_a_hand()`, and pass the `money` variable to it each time (you may need the method to then `return money`), but it's better to call it from a loop in the main method than to use needless recursion. In general, you don't want a method calling itself unless it makes the program more efficient or much easier to write, and even then you have to consider how deep the recursion will go.

Comment: Is one better than the other for any reason other than aesthetics?

Comment: One advantage to the loop is that each time `run()` is called it puts another round of variables on the stack and goes through unnecessary `imports`, while a loop keeps only one set of variables.

Comment: @BenDundee Yes, the function call stack doesn't keep building by run() calling itself over and over.

Comment: Ahh I see...this is a much better design.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest this is to add an argument to `run`:

```
def run(money):
```

remove the line `money = 500`, call `run` as `run(money)` in the loop and `run(500)` the first time.

I would suggest removing the 'play another round' logic from `run` as such

```
def run_single_hand(money):
    # <code to run hand, change value of money>
    return money

def play_hands():
     starting_money = 500
     money = starting_money
     money = run_single_hand(money)
     while True:
         # <code to ask if they would like to play again
         if again:
             run_single_hand(money)
         else:
             print 'thank you, you made a profit of %d' % money - starting_money
             break
```

as this avoids recursion issues (doing it the first way I suggested will end up with N calls to `run` on the stack) and still nicely factor your code.

For example, you could modify this to do poker my replacing `run_single_hand`.  This seems trivial for this example, but is a good code pattern for more complicated projects.

Comment: This is better because it's easier to control how much money the player starts with.

Answer (score 0):

Define your function like this:

```
def run(startingFunds = None):

    <brilliant code>

    money = 500 if startingFunds is None else startingFunds

    <brilliant code>

    if "y" in yn:
        print "\n" * 5
        run(money)
```

---

On second thought, do what iamnotmaynard suggests and put a while loop around it.But I would still take startingFunds as an argument to the function.

(PS: He gets the check :))